# batch insert/update using updateOrInsert() method and getting Array to string conversion

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8

I am trying batch insert and update with `updateOrInsert()` method. but I am getting array to string conversation error (by catch). Any Idea please tell. Thank you.

```
$arr = [];
for ($i=0; $i < count($request->data); $i++) {
    $arr[] = [
             'month' => $request->End_month,
             'year' => $request->start_Year,
             'data' => str_replace(',' ,'', $request->data[$i]),
             'cats' => $request->cat[$i],
             'created_by'=> $this->createdBy()
    ];
 }    //end for
 try {
     DB::table('total_ports')->updateOrInsert(
         ['year' => $request->start_Year], $arr
     );

    return redirect()->back()->with('successmsg', 'Lorem ipsum');
} catch (Exception $e){
    return $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: which part of the code is throwing the array to string conversion error?

Comment: first array inside updateOrInsert method.

Comment: if I use only insert method then It works like  DB::table('total_ports')->insert($arr);

Answer (score 0):

Look at:

https://laravel.com/api/master/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_updateOrInsert

In your code, you are passing a multidimensional array into the second argument (rather than a single-dimensioned array). This function will take that array as

```
[['key' => 'value'], ['key' => 'value'], ['key' => 'value'], ['key' => 'value']];
```

It will then take each individual internal array and try to interpret them as column/field names. so it is trying to convert `['key' => 'value']` to a string. For your updates, you will need to do them one at a time, unless you are trying to change many rows at once. In which case, you would use a combination of where() and update()